# text input doesn`t change on @media

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, media

I try to use this UI input but it doesn't change anything when I use media queries.

When I try another UI it works, but not for this one.

..............................................................................................................................................................

What is my code problem?

```css
.centered 
{
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.group {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
} 

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  color: #666666;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 36px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: .3s ease;
  text-align: center;
}
.input:valid ~ .label {
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}
.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.input:focus ~ .label {
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}
.input:focus ~ .bar:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.bar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff5126;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
.input:valid ~ .bar
{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3bb873;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)
{
 #centered-email
 {
  width: 100%;
 }
 
}
```

```html
        <div class="centered">
         <div class="group">
          <input type="text" class="input name" id="name" required autocomplete="off"/>
          <label class="label name-l" for="name">ایمیل</label>
          <div class="bar"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element with the `id` ->  `centered-email`.

Changed to be done -

Replace `#centered-email` with `.centered` in your media query and will fix your current issue.

Fixed snippet -

```css
.centered {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.group {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  color: #666666;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
  cursor: text;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 36px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: .3s ease;
  text-align: center;
}

.input:valid~.label {
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.input:focus~.label {
  top: 3px;
  font: 400 26px Roboto;
}

.input:focus~.bar:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.bar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff5126;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.input:valid~.bar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3bb873;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .centered {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" class="input name" id="name" required autocomplete="off" />
    <label class="label name-l" for="name">ایمیل</label>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well i call that Distraction ( just so shamefully ) but anyway, thank you :). i learned search in your codes before asking ;)

Comment: Typo's always happen... every developer's nightmare xD. Anyway happy coding mate :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess these are the problems:

> 1) Can't find div with id named "`#centered-email`".
>
> 2) Use `@media only screen` instead of `@media screen`

Check out this in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3ob20zwx/3/

Looks like working now. Hope you got what you were searching :) Good Day !

Comment: Using `@media screen` shouldn't be an issue. Its correct syntax as well.